# pretraining Neural nets to recognize patterns

Tags: conv-neural-network

I want a neural net to recognize bohemian patterns from normal floral patterns. This is a bit hard to distinguish. but once you see a lot of these patterns separately, you kind of get an intuition of what is bohemian and what is not. bohemians are basically tribal,paisely dense prints. and florals can also get dense but not be bohemian. i have attached a pic each of bohemian and not bohemian. 
my question is, i want to distinguish shirts having bohemian prints from normal semi formal florals. can i first train my conv net on floral vs bohemian patterns for it to get an intuition about the distinction between the two? and then use those weights to train with shirts data? i thought of this coz my shirts data is low and i can get a LOT of data with just prints.

Will pretraining help my network quickly pick up similar patterns and distinguish?
[image: Bohemian(paisely pattern)]

[image: Florals]

The first one is Bohemian(paisely) and the second is floral

Comment: From your question it is not clear how large is your dataset with shirt images.

Comment: i have 5 classes, each class has 2000 images. Yes, i can definetely crop and it will increase my dataset. but bohemian has variation which my training data has not seen. i did not find many mens shirts with a variety of bohemian patterns.

Comment: Having 2000 images per class in not so little. ImageNet contains about the same magnitude of images per class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of training on the patterns first and then fine-tuning on your shirt images, consider merging the datasets and training on the combined dataset.

Also, have you tried simply using a network pre-trained on general images and fine-tuning on your shirt images? This is usually a good starting point, so unless you already know this does not work, consider giving it a shot (if nothing else, at least to have a baseline).

As @Avis mentioned in their answer, data augmentation is a must when your dataset is small. However, there are other ways of getting more data. Have you considered obtaining more images from the internet? I have the impression that you should be able to get some more this way.

Comment: merging the dataset i feel is going to be a bad idea coz the network will learn the outer shape of the image i.e  think it should be square. i want it to learn the shirt outline and its pattern. hence i wanted to make it learn the pattern first.

Comment: Why do you think the network would learn the outer shape of the image? I think if you first train it on patterns only, it will later have problem moving towards shirt images, which might be avoided if you do it simultaneously. However, as I said, if I were you, I would first try training without the pattern pics, possibly using a pre-trained model for real world images, and see if this most straightforward approach works (I don't see why it shouldn't) *before trying anything fancy*.

Comment: Yes! thanks. I did intend to run just without first! i think it will coz currently, its learning the outer shape pretty strongly on my current data.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is common in Deep learning.

People use images that are available online to pre-train their networks & then train using custom images. You can also use augmenations to increase your dataset size.

Comment: true, but that is general pretraining. like teaching the classifier to generalize.  I want it to become specialized in distinguishing these prints as well. while i do not have many shirts with bohemian prints, even augmentation wouldnt increase it to a sufficient size. my question is will it help to train it with just the prints first?

Comment: It will help, but we cannot quantize "how much" until we train & check the performance. I've had similar experience before where I had to use anime/graphic images from internet for pretraining & classify real world objects.

Comment: And did it help? pretraining on anime images? did you do with pretraining and without pretraining?

Comment: I used inception pre-trained weights. It did help, but it was just an experiment. So didn't do much work on it though.